# Prevent stack overflow while crawling inside objects via reflection in c#

Tags: c#, reflection, recursion, stack-overflow

I have this method called MatchNodes:  `IEnumerable<bool> MatchNodes<T>(T n1, T n2)`

Which basically gets every property and field from both `T` objects (via reflection, and not including properties/fields from base classes) and compares them, returning the result as a IEnumerable of bools.

When it finds a primitive type or string, if just returns the `==` between them.

When it finds a type derived from a collection, it iterates each member and calls `MatchNodes` for each of them (ouch).

When it finds any other type, it calls `MatchNodes` for each property/field.

My solution is obviously asking for a stack overflow exception, but I don't have a clue on how make it better, because I have no idea how deep the objects will go.

Code **(try not to cry please, it's ugly as hell)**:

```
public static IEnumerable<bool> MatchNodes<T>(T n1, T n2)
    {
        Func<PropertyInfo, bool> func= null;

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))
        {
            String str1 = n1 as String;
            String str2 = n2 as String;
            func = new Func<PropertyInfo, bool>((property) => str1 == str2);
        }
        else if (typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            System.Collections.IEnumerable e1 = (System.Collections.IEnumerable)n1;
            System.Collections.IEnumerable e2 = (System.Collections.IEnumerable)n2;
            func = new Func<PropertyInfo, bool>((property) =>
            {
                foreach (var v1 in e1)
                {
                    if (e2.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
                    {
                        var v2 = e2.GetEnumerator().Current;
                        if (((IEnumerable<bool>)MatchNodes(v1, v2)).All(b => b == true))
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                if (e2.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else return true;
            });
        }
        else if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive || typeof(T) == typeof(Decimal))
        {
            func = new Func<PropertyInfo, bool>((property) => property.GetValue(n1, null) == property.GetValue(n2, null)); 
        }
        else
        {
            func = new Func<PropertyInfo, bool>((property) =>
                    ((IEnumerable<bool>)MatchNodes(property.GetValue(n1, null),
                    property.GetValue(n2, null))).All(b => b == true));
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where((property) => property.DeclaringType == typeof(T)))
        {
            bool result =func(property);
            yield return result;
        }

    }
```

What I'm looking at is a way to crawl into the objects without calling my method recursively.

**EDIT**

To clarify, example:

```
public class Class1 : RandomClassWithMoreProperties{
    public string Str1{get;set;}
    public int Int1{get;set;}
}

public class Class2{
    public List<Class1> MyClassProp1 {get;set;}
    public Class1 MyClassProp2 {get;set;}
    public string MyStr {get;set;}
}
```

`MatchNodes(n1,n2)` where `n1.GetType()` and `n2.GetType()` are `Class2` would return true if:

- Every `Class1` object inside `MyClassProp1` has the same `Str1`,`Int1` for both objects
- `MyClassProp2` has the same `Str1`,`Int1` for both objects
- `MyStr` is equal for both objects

And I won't compare any properties from `RandomClassWithMoreProperties`.

Comment: Without rewriting the method myself, any method that can be written as recursive can also be written as a loop. The difficulty of which can be non-trivial, but it's a known CS fundamental and one I've employed myself.

Comment: Even as a loop, you would still need to watch out for cycles in the object graph. Also, your recursive calls use `object` as the `T` generic parameter - this is probably not what you want since you check that `DeclaringType == typeof(T)`. What exactly are you trying to do? There is probably a better way.

Comment: Also, look what happens if you give it two strings: `foreach property in typeof(String).GetProperties()` it's going to call `func`, which is `str1 == str2`. This is probably not what you meant to do.

Comment: @default.kramer Yeah, `T` ends up being always of type object, unless I cast the objects to `dynamic` before calling MatchNodes. I have no clue of what problem casting to `dynamic` could cause, though.

Comment: The problem you need to solve is avoiding an infinite loop, not avoiding a stack overflow (the stack overflow is just a symptom of the disease). If any object has a property which is a class that has a parent property pointing back to it, you've got an infinite loop. That's just the simplest form of course. You could have a much less obvious cycle involving more than two objects. You're going to have to store a table of objects you've already started processing so you can avoid these loops.

Comment: @user978122, doing so using  a Stack<> to keep track, you would still get a stack overflow, just this time no room being available for the Stack to expand. The issue still somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a stack or queue to store the properties you want to compare. It goes along these lines:

```
 var stack = new Stack<Tuple<object, object>>();

 // prime the stack
 foreach (var prop in n1.GetType().GetProperties())
 {
     stack.Push(Tuple.Create(prop.GetValue(n1), prop.GetValue(n2));
 }

 while (stack.Count > 0)
 {
     var current = stack.Pop();

     // if current is promitive: compare
     // if current is enumerable: push all elements as Tuples on the stack
     // else: push all properties as tuples on the stack
 }
```

If you use a `Queue` instead of a `Stack` you get a BFS instead of a DFS. Also you should probably keep track of already visited nodes in a `HashSet`. You also might want to add a check to make sure the types of `n1` and `n2` are the same.

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem. I'll accept as answer, but I think I overcomplicated my solution. I may just compare each object manually since I'll only have to do it for 20~30 classes.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach here is to keep a breadcrumb trail of objects that you've touched, and passing that forward as you delve deeper.  For each new object, check to see whether it is in the graph of objects that you have already seen, and if it is, short circuit and bail out (you've already seen that node).  A stack is probably appropriate.

You are not likely to get stack overflows by comparing an acyclic object graph- it's when you end up with loops that things blow up.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the objects you already visited, in a `List<object>` for example (or `Set<>` or anything like that)...

Also, any recursion can be un-recursed using the stack that you'll control manually.